# Get all tables from MySQL via Spark

Tags: java, mysql, apache-spark

I'm learning Spark now and I know how to work with specific table.

But I want to load all tables from database. And the question is how to do it.

Here is my code with loading from specific table:

```
package gt.example.spark;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class App {
    public static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    public static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example";
    public static final String USERNAME = "root";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "pass";

    private static final JavaSparkContext sc =
            new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Example").setMaster("local[*]"));

    private static final SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
        options.put("driver", DRIVER);
        options.put("url", URL + "?user=" + USERNAME + "&password=" + PASSWORD);
        options.put("dbtable", "user");

        DataFrame jdbcDF = sqlContext.read().format("jdbc").options(options).load();
        jdbcDF.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to load all the table names? If so then query the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html).[`TABLES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html) table. You can use the same code as above but changing the `dbtable` property.